# Unabe to access iframe's contentDocument

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am adding an iframe like the following:

```
function addIframe() {

var x = document.createElement("iframe");

x.setAttribute("id", "PDFframe");

x.setAttribute("src", "http://localhost:8080/mywebsite/boxlabelpdf.htm");

x.setAttribute("style", "visibility:hidden;");

document.body.appendChild(x);

}
```

And then accessing the iframe like this in my code:

`var iframe = document.getElementById("PDFframe");`

and console logging `iframe` variable, which looks like Image #1 below

**Image #1 showing how iframe looks when console logged:**

[image]

**Image #2 - showing where base64 exists:**

[image]

I want to access the base64 string which is located inside `lastChild` as shown in the Image #2 below.
And `lastChild` is located inside `contentDocument` as shown in the Image #1.

So first I was trying to consoe log `iframe.contentDocument` but it gives me `<empty string>`. And it looks like a HTML document so I am wondering how can I access the base64 string located in `innerText` here?

Comment: Try `iframe.contentDocument.body.innerHTML`

Comment: @Barmar That comes out as `<empty string>` as well even though there is `innerHTML` and `innerText` showing base64 to me in the console log.

Comment: Is the page that's creating the iframe also in `localhost:8080`? If not, it won't be able to access the iframe contents.

Comment: Yes. It's working now. I had to add onload event for the variable `iframe`